# Setting multiple datasource for a report in Asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, report

I have a report whose data is derived from two stored procedures.so i need to set these two datasources for generating the report.But the reports which have only one SP, ie.only one datasource works properly. For setting the datasource, i wrote code like this:

---

```
dim reportdocument as ReportDocument

Dim reportPath As String = Server.MapPath("CrystalRpts\Report.rpt")

ReportDocument.Load(reportPath)

'Function for Setting the Connection

SetDBLogonForReport(MyConnectionInfo, ReportDocument)

dim dt1 as datatable=Datasource1

dim dt2 as datatable=Datasource2

dt1.merge(dt2)

reportdocument.setDataSource(dt1)

CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource=reportdocument

***************************************************

But, the report is not generating.it shows the following error

The Report requires additional information

Servername:- Server

Database:- Database

UserID:-

Password:-
```

> But the reports which have only one
>   SP, ie.only one datasource works
>   properly.What colud be reason for this
>   error?

I have already created this report.So i cant combine the two `SPs` as it may refresh the report fields.Please advice.

Comment: @Nandini What really do you want to do? your question is unclear?

Comment: @Nandini have a look at this it may help u http://p2p.wrox.com/crystal-reports/32661-report-you-requested-requires-further-information.html

Comment: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=61384

Answer (score 1):

you can set only one datasource to report, but its better you will get all you required  at once and set that source to your report.

```
Its better to combine your two Stored procedure to one
```

Comment: @Akthar i certainly go with your answer but look at the error she mentioned?

Comment: but She also write, if she use only 1 procedure, then its working fine.

Comment: no,i have already created this report.i cant combine the two SPs as it may refresh the report fiels. Also, for getting the two datasources together, i have merged the two.
Look at the line,
dt1.merge(dt2)